# ofstream is creating a file but writting only starting word not full string

Tags: c++, string, gcc, ifstream

This is My code. It makes a file but only prints he first word i input. Please help.

```
std::string userinput;
int a =rand() % 4+1;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << a;
std::string line = ss.str();
std::string mfile="C:\\Users\\Venom\\Documents\\atom\\c++\\projects   \\pyramid\\info files\\infernotxt\\help\\greeting\\" +line;
//std::cout << mfile << '\n';
std::ifstream infile(mfile.c_str());
getline(infile, line);
std::cout << infernoname<<line << '\n';
infile.close();


std::cout << username;
std::ofstream output(guestfolder.c_str());
std::getline(std::cin, userinput);
output<<userinput;
output.close();
```

Comment: Where is `infernoname` declared / initialized?

Comment: My advice is to use an IDE with a debugger (like Visual Studio). So you can step through your code executing it line by line looking at the variables at each step. That way you can quickly find out where the program does not do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is that you're using std::cin which only gets the first word of input. What you want to use is [getline(string)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

The problem: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvt5b.png). 
[Input/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXvCT.png)

---

getline usage, assuming `userinput` is a `std::string`

`std::getline (std::cin,userinput);`

Comment: but cin prints whole string. I think this won't work, but i'll give it a shot.

Comment: `std::cout` prints the whole string, but `std::cin` is for input and I think `>>` only takes up to whitespace. Experiment for yourself and see.

Comment: nop it did'nt work, just i said it won't. it did'nt even took input.

Comment: @Sid007 then you did something wrong. getline() will read the whole line.

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal is with your smug attitude when you're asking for help. What was your input and output? What was your code? There is 0 doubt that `getline` works. It's a function in the C++standard library that has been tested and used since 1998.

Comment: no i did as u told. it really did'nt ask for input. w8 let me edit my ques. and u can check the code. p.s i am not a good coder .

Comment: I recommend making a small program just to use getline and understand what it does. After that, read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739453/using-getline-with-file-input-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> var;` only reads until first space. In order to prevent this use `getline(cin, var);`